# Ras;pberry pi I2C AM2320

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I have a an AM2320 connected, and its address are as follows i2c_bus=1, i2c_addr=0x5c, i2c_slave=0x0703. I wrote code on the raspberry pi and it all works. I know there are is a device at 0x48, and I am not sure about 0x40, but when I run the command i2cdetect -y 1 I get

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Why don't I see the 0x5c device?

Comment: And what data sheet suggests about it?

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/3035617/0/0/1/am2320-product-manual.html?utm_adgroup=xGeneral&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search_EN_Product&utm_term=&utm_content=xGeneral&gclid=CjwKCAjwtpGGBhBJEiwAyRZX2tXhs8VZimZEudkK0USa7FVJ_VW8qs4CY5HAYpXG_kLaC1cSvg4n1RoCODIQAvD_BwE

Comment: If its a slave address does it should up with i2cdetect?